# ValueError: invalid literal for float(): when inserted substring from "2015-05-21T18:11:55" into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a key value pair in a JSON-derived dictionary that looks like this:

```
u'local_start_time': u'2015-05-21T18:11:55.000Z'
```

When I try to insert a portion of this string into a dataframe I get this error:

```
  File "fix_runs_prepare.py", line 63, in <module>
    df.set_value(i, name, str(g[name])[0:19])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1679, in set_value
    engine.set_value(series.values, index, value)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 118, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.set_value (pandas/index.c:3382)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.set_value (pandas/index.c:3264)
  File "pandas/src/util.pxd", line 60, in util.set_value_at (pandas/index.c:15472)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-05-21T18:11:55
```

This is when inserting using this call:

```
run_info = df['run_info']
for i in range(len(df['run_info'])):
    g = run_info[i]    
    for name in name_list:
        if g.get(name):
            if name is 'local_start_time':
                df.set_value(i, name, str(g[name])[0:19])
            else:
                df.set_value(i, name, g[name])
```

I get the same error if I don't first cast  to a string:

```
                df.set_value(i, name, g[name][0:19])
```

On the other hand if I just insert a string literal like "baloney" I do not get this error. I think something funky is going on because the string I am using begins with a number . That's why I tried explicitly casting to `str()` but since that didn't work I'm out of ideas. What else should I try?

**Addendum here df.head()

```
                        _id country      id_2  location_fail  no_location  \
0  55721992afe58716147ed3e8     NaN    212508            NaN            1
1  55721992afe58716147ed3e9     NaN    212508            NaN          NaN
2  55721992afe58716147ed3ea     NaN    212508            NaN          NaN
3  55721992afe58716147ed3ec     NaN    400134              1            1
4  557219d4afe58716147edbd4  Poland    513751            NaN          NaN

         run                                           run_info  gender  \
0  526956965  {u'tagged_users': [], u'hashtags': [], u'feed_...     NaN
1  512136570  {u'tagged_users': [], u'hashtags': [], u'feed_...     NaN
2  510056284  {u'distance': 0.0, u'playlist': [], u'author':...     NaN
3  525398093  {u'motivation': {u'duration': 1.5, u'distance'...     NaN
4  477634373  {u'tagged_users': [], u'hashtags': [], u'speed...     NaN

   weight  height  ...   descent  calories  heart_rate  heart_rate_max  steps  \
0     NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN    NaN
1     NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN    NaN
2     NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN    NaN
3     NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN    NaN
4     NaN     NaN  ...       NaN       NaN         NaN             NaN    NaN

   notes  speed_avg  heart_rate_avg  speed_max  local_start_time
0    NaN        NaN             NaN        NaN   NaN
1    NaN        NaN             NaN        NaN   NaN
2    NaN        NaN             NaN        NaN   NaN
3    NaN        NaN             NaN        NaN   NaN
4    NaN        NaN             NaN        NaN   NaN
```

Comment: What does your `df` look like?

Comment: @tuananh just put that into the body of my question

Comment: How about explicitly set the datatype of your column to `str`: `df[[name]] = df[[name]].astype(str)`

Comment: @tuananh that did the trick! Can you put that in as a real answer and I'll mark it as such? I think this might be useful to others as I wasn't able to find any other SO postings with exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `pandas.dataframe` treats datatype of all cells as `object` and even try to [infer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) the datatype if you don't specify it explicitly.

To avoid that, explicitly set the datatype of columns you want to, using `dataframe.astype`:

```
df[[name]] = df[[name]].astype(str)
# Or
df[[name]] = df[[name]].astype(float)
```